# Permission dialog is not showing in version 5.0

Tags: android, permissions

`android permission dialog` is not showing in `lollipop version I.e 5.1`, but `permission dialog` is showing in version 6.0 ie `marshmallow`. Can any one tell me what is the reason behind this, and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Because runtime permission is added in version 6.0. Check https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html for more information.

Comment: Run time Permissions works form android 6.0 for 6.0 below you should declare permissions in android manifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

For below `Android 6.0` permission dialog will not shown to the user.

From [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> 1. If the device is **running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower**: If you list a dangerous permission in your
>      manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the
>      app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install
>      the app at all.
> 2. If the device is **running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher**: The app has to list the permissions in the
>      manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while
>      the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and
>      the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user
>      denies a permission request.

Comment: This is correct but incomplete. Please add a quote from Android Docs or some other reliable source tp make it complete.

Answer (score 0):

> Can any one tell me what is the reason behind this

Assuming that you mean the [runtime permission dialog triggered by `requestPermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), the reason is that this dialog exists only on Android 6.0+. `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`, `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`, and related methods call their native equivalents on Android 6.0 devices and fail gracefully on older devices.

> how to solve this problem.

There is no problem. Runtime permissions only exist on Android 6.0+. On Android 1.0-5.1 devices, permissions are granted purely at install time.